# Where to put rooks when many pawns breaks are possible ( example position )

Tags: pawn-structure

I think the white plan is to move the king to d3, knight to d2 (to protect f1/f3 from black bishop) put the bishop an a3 and open position c4-c5. I think the white position is much better. Is it the correct plan?

**But how to decide where to put rooks, there are so many possible breaks in this position on the queenside.**

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This KID totally went south for Black. Stockfish gives a solid +1 to 1.5 advantage, and suggests Black should play a5 better sooner or later, after which the White rooks already stand good where they are. Black's lack in space will give him a no-fun defense. c5 will be played anyway. I tried to play the Black side, and quickly let it plummet to +3. A total nightmare. (Overprotecting c5 with Bf8 doesn't help as this costs e5 if you intend dxe5.)

Thus the answer: Let the rooks stand and immediately break with c5. a5 isn't really bad either but c5 is the standard KID plan anyway.